# Los datos tienen valor Null. No se puede llamar a este método o propiedad con valores Null

Tags: c#, .net

Cómo puedo arreglar para que me acepte el *valor de null*.

`otra2 = nw12Reader.GetString(nw12Reader.GetOrdinal("SI_Ubicacion_Fisica"));`

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar la función `IsDBNull`, de la siguiente forma:

```
if (!nw12Reader.IsDBNull(nw12Reader.GetOrdinal("SI_Ubicacion_Fisica")))
    otra2 = nw12Reader.GetString(nw12Reader.GetOrdinal("SI_Ubicacion_Fisica"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola podrías hacer uso de un ternario, es un if simplificado, está claro que necesita un string aunque sea vacío, tu código quedaría así:

```
if(nw12Reader.GetOrdinal("SI_Ubicacion_Fisica")!=null){
     otra2 = nw12Reader.GetString(nw12Reader.GetOrdinal("SI_Ubicacion_Fisica"));
}else{
      otra2 = nw12Reader.GetString("");
}
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[.net](/questions/tagged/.net)

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: @Eduard acabo de editar la rp